# Why did 人艰不拆 get banned?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[人艰不拆 百度百科](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=gACWYYCTWCWPV6JyC5A3RtrYVTNTf190kUShqV37ZNn_uMHPq6XR1BZrdHUuug8tJiBlHSGhXZyqwbiWBwCkJSivUAdq2zGZ1RprPq5VX57)

> 人艰不拆（读音rén jiān bù chāi），网络语，意思是“人生已经如此的艰难，有些事情就不要拆穿”。该词语出自林宥嘉歌曲《说谎》，“别说我说谎 人生已经如此的艰难，有些事情就不要拆穿”后常被网友在回帖中引用，楼主直接说出了一个事情的真相，只是让人一时无法直接面对的意思。“人艰不拆”已经在国家新闻出版广电总局今2014年11月27日发出的通知中被明令禁止使用。

- Why did 人艰不拆 get banned?

Comment: Because it's not a *standard* chengyu? Anyway, guessing what "广电总局" are thinking is meaningless to me...BTW `NBA` and `GDP` was banned too.

Comment: Here's the [reason](http://www.sarft.gov.cn/art/2014/11/27/art_31_747.html): "reckless distortion or misuse of chengyu". Anyway, as the title of the document states, it's only banned in broadcasting/TV programs and ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chengyu (or idiom) is a cultural thing.

"Getting banned" is an administrative(political) thing.

Another thing is that your quoted message is not accurate. The original order was from 《关于规范广播电视节目用语推广普及普通话的通知》（广发【2013】96号）, which was to clarify the usage in broadcasting programmes for popularizing Putonghua.

Now why? Because Putonghua has an official standard, the official channels should keep their standard.

Answer (score 0):

广电总局is the official management office of TV/broadcasting/movie, and this rule is only for those official issues. It's not affecting oral/bbs/social network and so on